# does the @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite must be static?

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

i saw many examples and in each one of them i didn't saw any mention about static needed in beforeSuite and afterSuite in testNG

my scenario is that i have MainRunner and BaseTest that extend the MainRunner

MainRunner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { testRunner.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
}

 public class baseTest {
static WebDriver driver;
public static mainPage main;
public static culturePage mainCulturePage;
public static mainArticle mainArticle;
```

BaseTest:

```
@BeforeSuite
public static void setup() {
   //locating the driver and maximize the browser window
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "F:\\java-projects\\.AB-Settings Folder\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver= new ChromeDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      //create reporting folder and report
      //init();


      main = new mainPage(driver);
      mainCulturePage = new culturePage(driver);
      mainArticle = new mainArticle(driver);

}


@AfterSuite
public static void close() {
    //extent.flush(); 
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

so the question is why do i need to make it static? (the classes, and the annotations) in order these to run?and what is the explain of the static beside these that it works outside the instance and no need for instance?

also what is the options to change of the deprecated:

```
testng.addListener(tla);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multilevel inheritance to make your code more structured and easy to maintain and you can do it without using any static method.
For example:

```
public class ClassA {

public void setUp() {
    // Perform the setup operation of the driver here
}

public void closeDriver() {
    // Close the driver here
    }
 }

public class ClassB extends ClassA{

@BeforeSuite
public void initializeDriver(){
    //Call the setUp method from ClassA here
    setUp();
}

@AfterSuite
public void closeDriver(){
    //Call the closeDriver method from ClassA here
    closeDriver();
    }

//Add all the other BeforeClass and AfterClass also in this class .    

}

public class ClassC extends ClassB{

@Test
public void testMethod(){
    // Write your test method here
  }

}
```

So by using above multilevel inheritance, you don't need to make any method static and whenever your @Test starts, it will automatically run the ClassB methods which would do the initialising and the closing driver part of the script.

And to answer to your deprecated part of question, you can use @Deprecated annotation before the method when you know that the method is now deprecated so as to not use the method again in future.

Please let me know if it helps!!

Comment: yes it helps, but i think i can change it bit more, the reason i have a problem with the static is because the initialising  accure only once at the start but than the main instance is empty, than after these another class want to use these methods on the main class and he can't cause it only accesable once and only on the start, so your solution will make it help in the way that the initialising will be once but the object can be accessable from anywhere.

about the deprecated, is there something that change these method as new method?

Comment: Nope, you cannot change a deprecated method as new method since that is part of the library/framework which we have no control over.
Deprecated annotates that this method will be removed in future versions/releases of framework. It is used to suggest the developer to move on to new method and stop using deprecated method.
Let me know if this helps, please upvote and accept the answer if it solves your problem.
Happy to help you!!

Comment: so there is new method instead of these old one?


        
          public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
      TestNG testng = new TestNG();
      testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestRunner.class });
      testng.addListener(tla);
      testng.run();
      }

Comment: Yes, 
Use addListener(ITestNGListener) instead
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
tng.addListener((ITestNGListener) tla);    

Please upvote the answer as well, if it solves your problem :)

Comment: can you send it with the correct syntacs here as code? i get it not correct

Comment: Please check now, Use `addListener(ITestNGListener)` like

`TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();`
`tng.addListener((ITestNGListener) tla);`

You can refer this link as well: `https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1683`
      
And sorry to ask again, but i see you have accepted answer, please upvote it as well, thanks!!

Comment: still something is wrong and it get's two much red lines:

     `public static void main(String[] args) {
  //TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
  addListener(ITestNGListener);
  tng.addListener((ITestNGListener) tla);
  TestNG testng = new TestNG();
  testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestRunner.class });
  //testng.addListener(tla);
  testng.run();
 }`

Comment: Use these 3 lines of code: `TestNG tng = new TestNG();` `TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();` and `tng.addListener((ITestNGListener)tla);` 
Let me know if it works

Comment: now it worked, so instead of:

    `TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
  TestNG testng = new TestNG();
  testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestRunner.class });
 testng.addListener(tla);
 testng.run();`
i can now do:
    `TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
  TestNG testng = new TestNG();
  testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestRunner.class });
                testng.addListener((ITestNGListener)tla);
 }`
we avoid these two lines
`testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();`
and change them with one :
`testng.addListener((ITestNGListener)tla);`

Comment: Yes and great that it worked. Please upvote the first answer that i replied to your question. Currently, you can see the accepted tick on the answer, please upvote it as well. Happy to help you :)

Comment: by the way, what these line do:
`testng.run();`